# Using Householder Transformation on a 3x3 matrix with rank2

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0\\ 
-3 & 2 & 1\\ 
6 & 5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ be a matrix with $rank(A)=2$. Transform A into an upper triangular matrix using housholder transformation.

I'm not sure how to do so in a matrix that is not full-ranked.. Any suggestions/rsources to search it?

Comment: Just do the same that you would if it were full-ranked

Comment: Well I'm not really used to be given info that aren't needed in the solution. I mean what's the point of saying the rank=2 then?